# Malicious IP addresses

Tags: malware, databases, ip, network-scanners, botnet

I am looking for updated lists of IP addresses that belong to malware's C&C, botnets, malicious scanners, or other sort of malicious activities.

Is there any public database of malicious IP addresses?

Comment: Why do you want this? Such a database, if made public, would quickly invalidate itself and become uselessly unreliable, if it even was reliable to begin with (which isn't likely). Your question smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248725). Please clarify your end goal.

Comment: different goals, see how they are distributed geographically, add them to my blacklist, ...

Comment: Here's one.
<s>https://www.malwaredomainlist.com/</s><br> https://www.malwaredomainlist.com/mdl.php Last update: 2017

Comment: Thanks, it hasn't been updated since 2017.

Comment: You need a supplier such as google or microsoft to deliver up-to-date lists of these domains, ip's and so forth

Comment: Or at least businesses who are busy with doing this

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139743)

Answer (score 2):

There are several freely available threat intelligence feed around.

See e.g. https://threatfeeds.io/

Do note that such lists are ephemeral in nature. Which IPs are currently being used for malicious activity is ever changing, and the information generally decreases in value as soon as it is openly published. For this reason, most high-quality threat feeds come from organizations that either sell them, or only share them with trusted partners.